# How to save a string/object to firebase database

Tags: javascript, database

Noob question... Using JS, how do I save a string or object to firebase database? I'm trying to do this on codepen.io. I've tried this:

```
// Initialize Firebase app

const firebaseConfig = {
  // your app config here
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get a reference to the database

const database = firebase.database();

// Write a string to the database

const myString = "Hello, Firebase!";

database.ref('myData').set(myString);
```

But I'm not seeing anything added in the firebase console... What steps am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your firebaseConfig is empty.
Put your Firestore information in there like this:

```
  const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
      authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
      projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
      storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
      messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
      appId: "YOUR_APP_ID"
    };
```

I couldn't get it to work in Codepen but I made a simple javascript project and ran it with node.js.

If you don't have Firebase imported into your project,
do it like this:

```
npm install firebase
```

You then should import the required libraries to your project:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
```

Lastly you can connect to the collection and read/write data like this:

```
const testCol = collection(db, 'TestCollection');
const testSnapshot = await getDocs(testCol);
const testList = testSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
console.log("Test list",testList);
```

This is a useful site that explains it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: I did all this, I just posted a template. My firebaseConfig is filled with all the relevant stuff.

Comment: I see. Then have you tried making the connection on a local project? I can't seem to import the Firebase library successfully on codepen. I got it to work locally though.

You can easily make a simple project (if you have node.js installed) with this command in your terminal: npm create vite@latest

Comment: I wanted it to work with a nextjs project I'm currently working on but npm install firebase always ends with an error. I'll try again tonight. Thank you

Comment: `npm i firebase` should work. If you get an error, it is probably because of a different package in package.json that is causing the error. You could try deleting the node_modules folder and retry `npm i`. If not, show me the error.